# How do I change the DNS server on Kubuntu?

Tags: networking, kde, dns, settings

I would like to change the DNS server for my Kubuntu computer so I can do anything while surfing the web.

Can someone please help show me how it is done?

Comment: If "*my uncle did it before but wont tell me how to change the DNS on my Kubuntu computer so i can do anything while surfing the web*", then he probably did it for a good reason (like keeping you from visiting specific web sites), and without knowing how/where he did that, it's difficult to come up with a solution.

Answer (score 8):

The simplest way to set your own DNS servers is shown below. (*This may, or may not, solve your problem, as we don't know what changes your Uncle made to limit your Internet access.*)

[image]

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use a specific DNS server, you can set up your network connections manually.

These options are under **System Settings > Network > Connections**.

Open the individual settings for your network.  You will want to make the following changes to your IPv4 and IPv6 settings.

- Change **Method** to "Manual".
- Put the IP address of your desired DNS server under **DNS Servers**.  Cloudflare Privacy DNS (1.1.1.1) is used here as an example.

In the box below, "Add" your computer's local IP address:

- **Address** is the local IP address for your device (your computer).  If you don't know it, type `ip address` into a terminal.  Your local IP address will be one of the ones listed after the word `inet` and will have an address in the DCHP reservation block for your router.
- **Netmask** should default to 255.255.255.0
- **Gateway** is the IP address of your router (or whatever device on your network handles DHCP and assigns a local IP address to your device)
- Select "IPv4 is required for this connection" if you want to restrict access to IPv4 only.  Otherwise you will need to set up the IPv6 tab using IPv6 type addresses.
- Accept these new settings, then open a terminal and run `sudo service network-manager restart` or just reboot your computer.

[image: image of settings screen]

---

It is recommended that you set a DHCP reservation on your router to match the local IP address you entered.  Otherwise, your local IP address can change and these settings would need to be changed each time.  You will need to consult the documentation for your router if you wish to do this.

Answer (score 0):

On my system I found I had to edit `/etc/resolv.conf` each time after the connection was established.

Not ideal, but it worked.

I ran `nslookup google.com` to check which DNS server was being used before and after editing.